# Error when clicking element::: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: d is undefined

Tags: selenium-webdriver

**Scenario**:  In an application, I have collapsed button on expanding that, its submenu are listed and clicking on submenu open that particular page.

Getting the following error when clicking:

```java
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: d is undefined
    Command duration or timeout: 10.07 seconds
    Build info: version: '2.31.0', revision: '1bd294d', time: '2013-02-27 20:53:56'
    System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.6.0_23'
    Session ID: 59cdfb73-3810-4de5-ae57-4410176c344d
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
    Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=17.0.1, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:187)
     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:79)
     at com.ptgi.dhpbx.core.BasePage.click(BasePage.java:79)
```

I am able to click on the collapsed button but not able to click on sub-menu using any of ID, xpath or CSS locator. Using javascript I am able to click.

**Next step**: There are checkboxes on the page and throws the same error when running the script. While recording with IDE two lines are recorded for checking the checkbox.

```java
click  "//input[@id='input-5']"
click  //section[@id='main']/article/div[2]/div/div/div/ins
```

**DOM** is :

```html
    <section id="main" data-bind="router: { transition:'entrance' }">
    
    <article data-view="views/voicemail/voicemailSettings" style="" data-active-view="true">
    <header>
    <p data-i18n="pbx:voicemailSettings.subtitle">Specify which calls are sent to voicemail, send voicemail recordings to your email, change your voicemail passcode and set voicemail greetings.</p>
    <div class="emptyBlock20"/>
    <header>
    <div class="contentContainer">
    <div class="form-element indentRight">
    <div class="icheckbox-radio">
    <div class="icheckbox_square-blue focus hover">
    <input id="input-5" type="checkbox" data-bind="CustomCheckBox: {checked: allCallsToVm}, click: function() { busyCallsToVm(allCallsToVm()); noAnsCallsToVm(allCallsToVm()); } " name="forwardCallRadio" tabindex="5" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px none; opacity: 0;"/>
    <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px none; opacity: 0;"/>
    
    </div>
    <label class="" data-i18n="pbx:voicemailSettings.sendAllCallsToVM" for="input-5">Send all calls to voicemail</label>
```

Please help

Thanks,
Rakesh

Comment: Can you post the code too?

Comment: The code is                                                                                                        
`public void executexpath(String s)throws Exception{`
  `WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(s));`
  `JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;`
  `executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);`
 
`}`


// click on sumenu under collapsed menu

`executeJS("div.sub-nav-content.green");`


//Then on page click on check box and click on save

`click("//input[@id='input-5']");`

`click("(//a[text()='Save'])[1]");`

Comment: @FDM  If I am using javascript to click on the checkbox too, i am able to . So without using javascript it is throwing this error for any control.

Comment: your error says `d is undefined` - show the code where `d` is called please

Comment: @FDM, there is no variable defined as d. I am getting this error on click method.

Comment: What code is at BasePage.java:79